# Use HTML in PHP To add Drop Down Menu - populated from a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a drop down menu populated from  mysql database. Here is my code:

```
$sql=  "SELECT id, course_period_id from schedule WHERE STUDENT_ID='$_SESSION[student_id]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$options="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row["id"];
    $course_period_id=$row["course_period_id"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$course_period_id\">".$course_period_id.'</option>';
}
echo '</TD></TR></TABLE>';
echo '<SELECT>
                <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
                <?=$options?>
                </SELECT> ';
```

The problem is that it gives me a drop down menu with zero options. So what should I change in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using php tag when php tags are already open?

```
echo "<select>
      <option value=0>Choose</option>
      $options
      </select>";
```

Comment: Kindly [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if your problem is solved by this.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work.

```
    $sql=  "SELECT id, course_period_id from schedule WHERE STUDENT_ID='".$_SESSION[student_id]."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $options="";

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $id=$row["id"];
        $course_period_id=$row["course_period_id"];
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$course_period_id\">".$course_period_id.'</option>';
    }

    echo '</TD></TR></TABLE>';
    echo '<select>
        <option value="0">Choose</option>' . $options . '</select>';
```

You are not contactinaging the PHP variable correctly.

can't be used in any eco/print statements. Infact it itself is a PHP code and should only be used separately.

Ex - in a new php page you can do this

```
<select>
<option value="0">Choose</option>
<?=$options?> 
Suggested way is
<?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you checked for session that if session is setted or not! If setted then make sure that your session id matches your table column.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this
$sql=  "SELECT id, course_period_id from schedule WHERE STUDENT_ID='$_SESSION[student_id]'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        $options="";

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $id=$row["id"];
            $course_period_id=$row["course_period_id"];
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE='".$course_period_id."'>".$course_period_id."</option>";
        }
?>
       <SELECT>
            <OPTION VALUE="0" selected>Choose</option>
             <?php echo $options;?>
            </SELECT>
```